# In RPGLE how can i check the last 3 character of a 10 size variable to be a numeric or not

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a variable with size 10. it stores a 10 size value like 'KUNAL12345'. How can I check the last 3 characters of the value to be numeric or not. In this case the last 3 character is 345 which is numeric value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [%check](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/bbchk.htm) like this (i did not test)

```
dcl-c digits '0123456789';
dcl-s value char(10) inz('KUNAL12345');
if %check(%subst(value:8:3):digits) = 0;
  // each of the three last characters is a digit character
endif;
```

or as @jtaylor says

```
if %checkr(value:digits) < 8;
  // each of the three last characters is a digit character
endif;
```

Comment: @jtaylor___ also true edited my answer, thanks!

Comment: For the %CHECK case, instead of hardcoding the 8, you could use %SUBST(VALUE:%LEN(VALUE)-2) to start at the third-last character and go to the end of the string (no "length" parameter needed). But ... this isn't ideal either, since "2" isn't very self-documenting for "third last character".

Comment: in this case the syntax should be   :

if %checkr(digits:value) < 8;
  // each of the three last characters is a digit character
endif;               

not

if %checkr(value:digits) < 8;
  // each of the three last characters is a digit character
endif;

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sql regexp` functions.  The regex that matches 3 digits at end of a string is `\d\d\d$`

[here is a nice writeup](https://www.geekyramblings.net/2020/05/16/regex-in-rpg/)

```
d text            s             80a   varying
d match           s             80a   varying
d i5              s              5i 0
d numMatches      s             10i 0
 /free
      text        = 'steve 7335' ;

      exec sql
      set         :numMatches = regexp_count( :text, '\d\d\d$', 1 ) ;
      if          numMatches > 0 ;
      endif ;

      text        = 'steve 733z3' ;
      exec sql
      set         :match :i5 = regexp_substr( :text, '\d\d\d$', 1, 1 ) ;

      if          i5 = -1 ;
      // not a match
      endif ;
```